# GetElementby More Item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, listener, video.js

I use the VideoJS framework, i want know when the user pause the video. The video go to pause when i click on "Play button" and on video:

```
var vjs = document.getElementById("really-cool-video_html5_api"); // on video
var vjs = document.getElementById("really-cool-video").getElementsByClassName("vjs-play-control")[0]; // click button play
```

I with Listener, see if the user click on this "div" :

```
vjs.addEventListener("click", checkPause, false);
```

but it control only when i click on `document.getElementById("really-cool-video").getElementsByClassName("vjs-play-control")[0]` i want, both 2 div in my listener... I can't change the HTML and tell the div with the same name...  How i can do a Listener of two elements?

Comment: you are using the same variable name for both, it's only ever going to add the event listener to whatever vjs was set to last, use different variable names

Comment: i know... but how i can use : `vjs.addEventListener("click", checkPause, false);` for both div?

Comment: Purpose of jQuery tag?

Comment: vjs1.addEventListener ... vjs2.addEventListener ?

Comment: i want do it with only 1 var, because after i use more div and i can do confusion

Comment: then you would need an array and loop through the array.

Comment: mh, how i can do this loop? and , i can do it with JQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably better off using video.js's api to listen for pause events instead. There are ways to pause the video without clicking (keyboard control) and clicks that do not pause the video (play).

```
videojs('really-cool-video').on('pause', checkPause)
```

Comment: i've tried as it... but it doesn't work... and i've this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'w' of undefined , i use VideoJS API

Answer (score 1):

You have the same named variables your attaching listeners to. Try changing the second `vjs` to `vjsBtn` like so...

```
var vjsInnerBtn = document.getElementById("really-cool-video_html5_api"); // on video
var vjsPlayerBtn = document.getElementById("really-cool-video").getElementsByClassName("vjs-play-control")[0]; // click button play
```

Now you are free to accomplish this.

```
vjsInnerBtn.addEventListener("click", checkPause, false);
vjsPlayerBtn.addEventListener("click", checkPause, false);
```

Comment: yes i know, but i want do the listener one time with both div... not do two listener

Comment: im not sure I understand. Both will have different event variable names like vjsInnerBtn. But they will both have the callback of whatever the function checkPause is. Why on earth would you want both to have the same event variable names? What it sounds like you need is both having the handler function which this does.... You would eventually need a way to refer to each separately after delegation, regardless.

Comment: i want do this because i use a lot of getelementby

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming jQuery is available to you, since you've tagged it. This makes things much easier for you, because you simply have to fill the selector with the elements you want the event handler attached to:

```
$('#really-cool-video_html5_api, #really-cool-video .vjs-play-control').on('click', checkPause);
```

Note, this *still* adds multiple event handlers, this must be done if you want the same functionality triggered from a click on two different elements.

Answer (score 1):

have you considers store them in an array? like

```
var controls['video']  = document.getElementById("really-cool-video_html5_api"); // on video
controls['pause_btn'] = document.getElementById("really-cool-video").getElementsByClassName("vjs-play-control")[0];
//Here you add the addEvenListener with the array elements.
```

is the same approach to using different variables but you can iterate them if you want to attach them same event listener or use a function for that